# How to construct the POST data values in an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i've this piece of code that performs an AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
      url : 'inviaCommento.php',
      type : 'POST',
          data : {page: page, category: category} 
          dataType : 'json',
       success : function (msg)
            //...and so on
```

The problem is that i want to check if a search parameter is set, if yes i've to add the word to the data parameters.
The question is: can i costruct the data parameters before the call appendig values to it?
Something like this:

```
if $('#searchBtn').val()!=''
{
  data.append(search: $('#searchBtn').val())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, just create an array.

```
var data = {something: [], page: page, category: category, somekey: "default"};

data.something.push("a");
data.something.push("b");
if (...) {
    data.somekey = "new value";
}

$.ajax({
    ...
    data: data
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup, but `data` isn't a list, it's an object, so you just assign to the appropriate key.

```
var data = {page:page}; // ... current value of data: param in the $.ajax call
if($('#searchBtn').val()!=='')
{
  data.search= $('#searchBtn').val();
}
```

You'd put this above the `$.ajax()` call.